# How to append several phrases of a string to different lists in a loop

Tags: python, algorithm, sorting

it is actually really difficult to write a suitable title for this question, so please correct if you find something more percise.

My problem is basically, that I have a `txt file` with a pattern which i want to sort.

Consider the following `string`

```
url1
cust1
number1
url2
cust2
number2
url3
cust3
number3
url4
cust4
number4
```

So all the lines are seperated and the pattern is the same. What i want to do now is to make `3 lists` one for `url` one for `cust` and the last for `number`.

I have basically no idea how to do that as there is no pattern which I could search for with `regex`. So my idea was to do something like this:

```
for i in range(1, 3, len(txt)):
   l1.append(i)
```

And this i would do for all the 3 lists. Is there some other easier and more advanced solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
with open('path/to/input') as infile:
    lines = (line.strip() for line in infile)

    urls, custs, nums = zip(*zip(lines, lines, lines))
```

Output:

```
In [241]: urls
Out[241]: ('url1', 'url2', 'url3', 'url4')

In [242]: custs
Out[242]: ('cust1', 'cust2', 'cust3', 'cust4')

In [243]: nums
Out[243]: ('number1', 'number2', 'number3', 'number4')
```

Comment: You forgot the assignment.

Comment: So how does that work? Where do you set the variables? Thanks for your help

Comment: @grumpyp: oops! Sorry. Forgot to paste the variable names in there the first time. Updated now

Comment: Cool thanks mate. Just figured out, that not everything is the same pattern. Any idea how to fix this? Like the first 100 Lines are like that pattern, then some other line crashes the patterns.

Comment: @grumpyp: in that case, you'd have to do it in two separate batches, one for each pattern... unless you can find a way to detect whether a line is a url/cust/num just by looking at the line

Answer (score 1):

you could do something like this :

```py
url = list()
cust = list()
number = list()

for i in range(0, len(lines), 3):
   url.append(lines[i])
   cust.append(lines[i+1])
   number.append(lines[i+2])
```

Assuming `lines` is your file as a string list.

Comment: Or like `cust = lines[1::3]`.